# Adding two integer values by passing parameters through an applet

Tags: java, applet, parameter-passing, appletviewer

The following java program gets compiled successfully but when I try to run it using **appletviewer**, I get the following (in command prompt) with a message "**applet not initialized**" in the applet window.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
/*
<applet code="ParamDemo" width="300" height="300">
<param name="first" value="20">
<param name="second" value="30">
</applet>
*/
class ParamDemo extends Applet
{
int x,y,sum;
public void init()
{
x=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("first"));
y=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("second"));
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
sum=x+y;
g.drawString("Total Sum is"+sum,100,100);
}
}
```

in the Command prompt -

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Salman\Desktop>javac ParamDemo.java

C:\Documents and Settings\Salman\Desktop>appletviewer ParamDemo.java
load: ParamDemo is not public or has no public constructor.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class sun.applet.AppletPanel can not access a
member of class ParamDemo with modifiers ""
        at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:368)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(AppletPanel.java:793)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(AppletPanel.java:722)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:379)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I am unable to figure out the problem ...

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: The class must be marked as public, e.g. `public class ParamDemo extends Applet` vs. just `class ParamDemo extends Applet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ParamDemo is not public

indicates you shall write `public` before `class ParamDemo extends ...`.

If no access modifier (such as public) is given for class, it is only accessible within the same package - no wonder appletviewer has problems with it.

An explicit constructor shouldn't be neccessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the ParamDemo class as public and define a function:

```
ParamDemo() {
    //Construct your object here.
}
```

Within the class ParamDemo.